# Почему PostgreSQL не выводит мою таблицу?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Не могу посмотреть что находиться в таблицы Application_top, почему то PSQL не выводит ее. Пишу команду SELECT * FROM Application_top - и ничего не получаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конце запроса добавляйте точку с запятой.

```
SELECT * from Application_cart;
```

Так как запрос может быть многострочным, то `psql` ожидает `;`, чтобы понять где он закончился.